# Debian & apache deploying multiple applications

Tags: php, apache, networking, debian

I have small problem. 
I have two applications named `appA` and `appB` created using `PHP`. I would like to deploy them on `apache2` server at the same time to be able to test integration between them ( something doesn't work). So far I was editing everytime apache `VirtualHost` configuration in 
 `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sites.conf`

I was trying to edit my `Hosts` just by creating second `*.conf` file which look like:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
        ServerName appA
        ServerAlias appA
        DocumentRoot /var/www/appA
</VirtualHost>
```

into

```
<VirtualHost localhost/appA:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
        ServerName appA
        ServerAlias appA
        DocumentRoot /var/www/appA
</VirtualHost>
```

but then i just get apache restart error:

`[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name`

The main thing is that now I can get my appA on the address: `localhost` if my `sites-ebabled` conf is set `DocummentRoot` into `appA` and with B I have to change the configuration of `VirtuanlHost`

Goal is to have appA under `localhost/appA` and appB under `localhost/appB`

I do realise that I have to edit `DNS` or `host` file but can anyone help me out because I'm out of ideas..

Comment: A virtual host is just a hostname and optional port, it doesn't include a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one VirtualHost and many directories:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
        ServerName myServer
        ServerAlias myServer
        DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>

 Alias /appA "/var/www/appA"
 <Directory /var/www/appA>
   Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>

 Alias /appB "/var/www/appB"
 <Directory /var/www/appB>
   Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Then you just access them using

```
http://localhost/appA
```

or

```
http://localhost/appB
```

Since your VirtualHost is at port 80.

Comment: I got HTTP 500:`Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: Take a look at apache logs, there must be something more about this error there. This conf was just copied from my working host.

Comment: Ok, after some changes it work perfect. Thank you !